# Reachability Module

Tags: objective-c, node.js, swift, server, reachability

Sorry for all the questions regarding this app. I have been struggling on coding this app for days.

As you might  have seen from my previous questions, I am currently trying to build an app that checks if a website server is up or down.

I have read many old stack overflow questions and they say to use the reachability module. When I go to the apple reachability module, it seems to be outdated.

Does anyone have any other solutions to this app? My goal is to ask the user to enter how many ever websites they want and then the app checks if they are up or down.

Comment: "to enter how many ever websites they want"  Come again?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I want the user to enter a website and then the app should check if that website server is up or down.

Comment: And what do you need `Reachability` for?  It won't tell you whether or not some URL that you point to is reachable.  It will only tell you whether or not your device is connected to the outside world.

Comment: I am not sure if I would need reachability or not. What should I use instead of reachability if it does not work for what I need?

Comment: Why not start by just loading the website's URL? You can get smarter, but this simple approach at least won't give you any false positives.

Comment: make a URL request and then check for response . If response code is 503 then the server is down.

Comment: @CRD I did that. google.com seemed to be loading fine.

Comment: So you determined Google was up. Isn't this what you are trying to do? Run the same test against a server you know is down. (You'll need a server you can control to test your app properly)

Answer (score 0):

make a URL request and then check for response . If response code is 503 then the server is down. you can see the list of server responses [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and below code to check for responses

```
let url = URL(string: "Your Server URL")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { _, response, _ in
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print(httpResponse.statusCode) // if the response code is 503 then the server is down

    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: The English word 'below' is not an adjective.  Therefore, "see below code" is not the right grammar.

Comment: Code 503 tells you the server is *up* but the web service is *down*, you won't get a 503 from the server if it itself is down...